# VBA Regex - Grab Hour HH:MM from String

Tags: regex, vba, excel

Given a arbitary string I want to grab an hour (HH:MM) from the string.

Here is my regex:

```
^                   # Start of string
(?:                 # Try to match...
 (?:                #  Try to match...
  ([01]?\d|2[0-3]): #   HH:
 )?                 #  (optionally).
 ([0-5]?\d):        #  MM: (required)
)?                  # (entire group optional, so either HH:MM:, MM: or nothing)
$                   # End of string
```

And my code:

```
Public Sub RegexTest()

 Dim oRegex As Object
 Dim time_match As Object

 Set oRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
 With oRegex
  .Global = True
 .Pattern = "^(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)$" 'HH:MM
 End With


 Dim s As String: s = "START TIME: Mar. 3rd 2016 12:00am"

 Set time_match = oRegex.Execute(s)
 If time_match.Count = 1 Then
   Debug.Print time_match.Matches(0)
 Else

 End If


End Sub
```

However I am unable to match here and get no output.

Comment: Remove `^` and `$` and use `(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d` pattern. See https://regex101.com/r/wQ4mK9/1

Comment: If you are planning to use this procedure repeatedly, you would benefit from declaring the **oRegex** object as **Static**. See [When to use a Static variable](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/877/declaring-variables/16978/when-to-use-a-static-variable) for explanation and example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `^(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)$` pattern only matches a full string that starts with an optional `HH:` part, and and obligatory `MM` part followed with an obligatory `:`.

I suggest

```
(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d
```

Since you are matching a *part of the string*.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wQ4mK9/1)

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. Would you know how to capture the time into a string using VBScript Regex? match.Matches(0) does not work